# What should I do with my question that only seemed ok because of my misunderstanding?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981010/why-is-php-unable-to-access-programs-in-the-windows-path-when-i-use-it-with-apac) which was I thought was a decent question at first. After I figured out (what I think at this point is) the actual cause to the problem that prompted me to ask the question, I don't think the question is actually useful anymore. I was really barking up the wrong tree and I feel kind of embarrassed for making anyone spend time looking at it, considering that.

Unfortunately, while I was in the process of figuring out my mistake, it got a few votes, and an answer from someone else who seemed to have spent some time on it. I posted another answer explaining my error. I'd really like to get rid of the question, but now I don't know if I'm missing some value in it, considering people voted for it. I don't think my few questions are really good, but I don't think any of them are particularly harmful. I feel like this one might actually be kind of misleading, but I don't know what to do about that.

Should I edit the question to make it more obvious what it turned out to really be about? I don't know if I should accept my own answer, or condense it into a comment. I guess I shouldn't delete the question it if it's upvoted, but I'm not really even totally sure about that. There are just so many dumb questions and I don't want to be responsible for another dumb question because I love this place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like a problem others may encounter and especially a solution which is non-obvious and unintuitive. Even though it may be an embarrassing and ultimately trivial issue, it seems to me that it can provide value to future visitors stumbling across the same issue.

For this purpose you may want to try to rephrase the question to add more relevant keywords or otherwise focus it more to make it easier for future visitors to find. Try to do so without invalidating the existing answer. Then go ahead and accept the answer that solved the problem and you've contributed a decent new problem with solution to the interwebs.